# single page in laravel

Tags: laravel, singlepage

I work with Laravel v5.7 !
 I have CourseController that controll all things about Courses . all things was ok but now i have problem . in my single page of courses any title or .. returned null .

```
public function single(Course $course)
{
    $course = Course::get()->first();
    $comments = $course->comments()
        ->where('approved', 1)
        ->where('parent_id', 0)->latest()
        ->with('comments')->get();
    return view('Home.course', compact('course', 'comments'));
}
```

Here is my controller code . when i use first() at all my singlepage i have same title and image ,..... and if i delete the first() u have this error :

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::comments does not exist.

I use `{{ $course->title }}` for showing course data in singlepage .
but for all slugs and courses return only first row of Db .

Please help me if you can ! ThankYou

Comment: Are you trying to get all approved comments for the first course only or for all courses?

Comment: No , i want to show title and ... ind single page with comments ! 
but if i delete the first i have errors

Comment: OK, the columns (approved, parent_id) in which table ?

Comment: Comment table my friend

Answer (score 1):

This will return the first course with its comments, and you can call `$course->title` directly in your blade.

```
public function single(Course $course)
{
    $course = Course::with(['comments' => function($query){
        $query->where('approved', 1)->where('parent_id', 0);
    }])->fisrt();
    $comments = $course->comments;
    return view('Home.course', compact('course', 'comments'));
}
```

OR

This will return all courses which have comments approved and parent_id = 0, and in your blade you have to make a loop on courses:

Controller:

```
public function single(Course $course)
{
    $courses = Course::with(['comments' => function($query){
        $query->where('approved', 1)->where('parent_id', 0);
    }])->get();
    return view('Home.course', compact('courses'));
}
```

blade:

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
    {{ $course->title }}
    $foreach($course->comments as $comment)
          {{ $comment->id }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: i want to show only one course with there comments not all courses my friend

Comment: Ok, use the first code I posted above, which ends with  ->first()

Comment: Tnx . it is ok but in all slugs(all courses) i have same text and title. it returns only first row of Db . imagine that you go to two page of site and all things of both are same ! can help me to edit it?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently overwriting the `$course` variable with the first instance in the database.

```
public function single(Course $course)
{
    // $course = Course::get()->first(); <- This gets the first Course also if you use first, don't use get
    $comments = $course->comments
        ->where('approved', 1)
        ->where('parent_id', 0)
        ->latest()
        ->with('comments')
        ->get();
    return view('Home.course', compact('course', 'comments'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick replay. when i use your code i have this error :
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'approved' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `courses` where `approved` = 1 and `parent_id` = 0 order by `created_at` desc)

Comment: I fixed the `$comments`

Comment: Thanks , but i have errors :
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::latest does not exist.

after adding () in front of comments i have no title or body in view but fix that error

Comment: Try using last() instead of latest()